# YouTube captions example

Tags: youtube, gdata

Can anyone provide an example of how to retrieve captions for YouTube video?

Based on API docs, API request https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&caption&v=2

returns list of videos about surfing with captions.

However a request for the first video from the list

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/bQX4fustG9Q?v=2&key=DEVELOPERKEY
```

returns feed that shows no traces of captions.

What am I missing?

Can someone please post an example of request that will retrieve captions for that video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions), you don't need to send any special parameters in the initial request, but instead retrieve videos normally and then look for the link with `rel=http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.captionTracks`.

Note that the caption link is only visible to the owner of a video.